# How to set Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise experimental to true?

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

```
PS C:\Users\Together> docker -H "npipe:////./pipe//docker_lcow" version
Client: Docker Engine - Enterprise
 Version:           18.09.7
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        b81f47481d
 Built:             06/27/2019 17:58:58
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:          master-dockerproject-2019-07-01
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.12.6
  Git commit:       e105a74
  Built:            Tue Jul  2 00:16:45 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

I can't seem to find where or how to set the client to experimental?

Answer (score 1):

To set the client's experimental property to true, add:

```
"experimental":  "enabled"
```

to the config.json file in the `.docker` folder in your home directory.